# Behavior of close button in a WXPython frame?

Tags: python, wxpython

What is the default behavior of the close button and how do I customize it? Specifically, I want to exit from a main loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle [wx.CloseEvent](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CloseEvent-class.html).

Comment: ...and WxApp apps have ExitMainLoop(). Thanks, I was kinda close!